# How to resolve this asp.net mvc routing issue - removing page (optional) for the first page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I force URL first page without page number? 
Here is the exact code I use.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyPictureQuotes",
                "picture-quotes/{PictureQuotesPage}", 
                new { controller = "Quote", action = "PictureQuotes", PictureQuotesPage = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

---

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Picture Quotes", "MyPictureQuotes", null, new { title = "Picture Quotes", PictureQuotesPage = string.Empty })%>
```

**It returns 
"/picture-quotes/5" instead of

"/picture-quotes" from the page

"http://localhost:2489/picture-quotes/5"**

It seems the routing value page 5 is carried over.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct overload of Html.RouteLink.  Use the following:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Picture Quotes", "MyPictureQuotes", 
    new { PictureQuotesPage = string.Empty }, 
    new { title = "Picture Quotes" })%>
```